# Complex generic stack

Tags: c, types, stack, ansi-c

I have been assigned to program a generic stack in ANSI C. It is meant to be for primitive datatypes. Until here there was no big problem whatsoever.

Afterwards I was asked to reprogram my application so that even complex data types can be used on my stack. I have searched and researched for the last week and I found nothing that could be helpful enough.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "genstacklib.h"
void (*freefn) (void*);

/*
 * ToDo
 */
void GenStackNew(genStack *s, int elemSize, void (*freefunk) (void*))
{
    s->elems = malloc (elemSize * GenStackInitialAllocationSize);
    freefn = freefunk;
    assert (s->elems != NULL);
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->logLength = 0;
    s->allocLength = GenStackInitialAllocationSize;
}
/* 
 * ULStackPush adds an element to the stack and allocates new memory if
 * needed. If there is not enough memory, ULStackPush does nothing.
 */
void GenStackPush (genStack *s, const void *elemAddr)
{
    /*assert (sizeof(*elemAddr) == s->elemSize);*/
    assert (s->elems != NULL);

    if (s->logLength == s->allocLength)
    {
        void *temp = NULL;

        temp = realloc (s->elems, 2 * s->allocLength * s->elemSize);
        assert (temp != NULL);
        s->allocLength = 2 * s->allocLength;
        s->elems = temp;
    }
    memcpy(currentval(s), elemAddr, s->elemSize);
    s->logLength = s->logLength + 1;
}

void GenStackPop (genStack *s, const void *elemAddr)
{
    assert (s->elems != NULL);
    assert (s->logLength != 0);
    (s->logLength)--;
    memcpy((void *)elemAddr, currentval(s), s->elemSize);
}

void *currentval(genStack *s)
{
    assert (s->elems != NULL);
    return ((size_t*)s->elems + s->logLength * s->elemSize);
}

bool GenStackEmpty (const genStack *s)
{
    assert (s->elems != NULL);
    return s->logLength == 0;
}

void GenStackDispose (genStack *s)
{
    assert (s->elems != NULL);
    s->logLength = 0;
    free (s->elems);
    freefn();
}
/*
 * ToDO
 */
void *freefn (void *) {
    free
```

And my header data is:

```
#ifndef GENSTACKLIB_H
#define GENSTACKLIB_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#define GenStackInitialAllocationSize 4

typedef struct
{
  void *elems;
  int elemSize;
  int logLength;
  int allocLength;
} genStack;

void GenStackNew (genStack * s, int elemSize);
bool GenStackEmpty (const genStack * s);
void GenStackPush (genStack * s, const void *elemAddr);
void GenStackPop (genStack * s, const void *elemAddr);
void GenStackDispose (genStack * s);
void *currentval(genStack *s);
#endif
```

In the first block of code, I believe that what has to be done is in the ToDo markings.
How can I make it to use my stack for complex data types?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by complex datatypes?

Comment: Let's say: Strings or char** or everything which is not primitive substantially

Comment: Have you considered using templates?

Comment: @Prabhu Templates in C ? I dont think they exist there as a prt of standard...

Comment: ^huh.. My bad. Didn't see the tags properly. Assumed it was C++.

Comment: You can store a pointer to the object. Storing the entire object is not trivial.

Comment: You can look at khash / kvec - that is macro C library with imho similar functionality you want (http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/) - but it is more advance C coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any problem with "complex" types like strings... there is no real difference bewteen pointer to string and pointer to int. So just store pointers (or pointers to pointers) and that should work.

So instead of element to be "int".. element is pointer to pointer.

Basic idea in form of very "pseudo" C code

```
typedef struct Wrapper 
{
 void * primitiveData;
} Wrapper;


void PrimitivePush(void * data)
{
 Wrapper * w = malloc();
 w->primitiveData = malloc();
 memcpy(w->primitiveData, data);

 ClassicComplexTypePush(&w)
}

ClassicComplexTypePush(void ** data)
{
  push data to stack
}
```

Comment: But it will cause problem in storing integer or other smaller type.

Comment: That is the idea. It is meant to work wherever I want to primitives or nor primitives

Comment: You can create bounding type for primitive types and have to type of "push" methods. One for primitve and one for complex type. Inside it will be the same, but primitive push wrap your input inside new struct and stroe pointer to pointer as well

Comment: @MartinPerry can you help me with a code example? I don't fully understand it.

Comment: The only thing here that is not that easy to be done, is the free(). WE dont know what kind of types there will be put in and there is no chance we can know how many times we should call the free()

Comment: You can solve it by adding flag to wrapper it it hold basic or complex type. But than you have to create wrapper also for complex type and have void * and void ** pointer in it. For complex type, void ** will be used, for classic void * will be used. According to this info, you can correctly free it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Consider using a singularly linked list for implementation, since when
```

using a stack, we don't know how many items may be needed.

Use a byte* or (char*) to store the contents of memory, instead of a void* (which would also work, but we may need to pad the allocation, to include structs)

Copy memory into a new allocation, which is pushed onto the stack,
  then delete that used upon pop.

- each node has to be of the same type, or at-least the same size, 
  errors using wrong type though may be undesired
- pop can be either used to check if the stack is empty by passing (NULL) 
  or to actually pop the stack, by referencing the memory you want to set.

  ```
  typedef unsigned char byte;
  ```

Create the structures which will be used to keep track of the stack

```
    struct gStackNode {
        byte *data; 
        struct gStackNode *next;
    };

    struct gStack {
        unsigned size;
        struct gStackNode *head;
    };
```

Initialize the stack, including the size of the type we will be using

```
    void stack_initalize(struct gStack *stk, unsigned size) {
        if (!stk)
            return;
        stk->size = size;
        stk->head = (void*)0;
    }
```

Always, we need to manually free the stack, in-case not all were popped

```
    void stack_free(struct gStack *stk) {
        if (!stk)
            return;
        struct gStackNode *temp;

        /* step through the remaining stack, deleting each item */

        while(stk->head) {
            temp = stk->head->next;
            free((byte*)stk->head->data);
            free((struct gStackNode *)stk->head);
            stk->head = temp;
        }
    }
```

push an item onto the stack

```
    void stack_push(struct gStack *stk, void *data) {

        struct gStackNode *node = (struct gStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct gStackNode));
        struct gStackNode *temp = stk->head;

        node->next = temp;

        node->data = (byte*)malloc(sizeof(byte)*(stk->size));

        byte * src = (char*)(data);
        byte * dest = (char*)(node->data);

        unsigned n = stk->size;

        /* fill the new allocation with source data */

        for(;n;n--)
            *(dest++) = *(src++);

        /* the node becomes the new head */

        stk->head = node;

    }
```

Sometimes we don't want to use a local variable ie: stack_pop_(stack, &type) we can use stack_push_arg_no_ref(stack, 10).

```
    void stack_push_arg_no_ref(struct gStack *stk, void *data) {
        stack_push(stk, &data);
    }
```

Now we can pop, and use the same to peek, passing (NULL) to data will result in a peek,
returning (1) if there is an item in the stack, and a (0) if its empty

```
    int stack_pop(struct gStack *stk, void * data) {
        if (!stk)
            return 0;
        if (!stk->head)
            return 0;

        if (data == (void*)0) {
            /*  
                simply check to see if the stack is empty or not
                don't actually pop the stack
            */
            return ((!stk->head == (void*)0));
        } else {
            struct gStackNode *next = stk->head->next;
            struct gStackNode *node = stk->head;

            unsigned i;
            byte *c_temp = (byte*)data;
            for(i=0;i<stk->size;i++)
                *c_temp++ = node->data[i];

            free((byte*)node->data);
            free((struct gStackNode*)node);
            stk->head = next;
        }
```

}

Finally we can implement the stack

using any ANSI C data types

- the size of a character string needs to be fixed
- structs can also be used

Using a character string

- CAUTION, for this example, the strings need to be NULL terminated, though
  it is possible to use non-NULL terminated strings

  ```
  char ta[32] = "ta: text 1";
  char tb[32] = "tb: text 2";
  char tc[32];

  struct gStack stack_char; stack_initalize(&stack_char, sizeof(ta));

  stack_push(&stack_char, ta);
  stack_push(&stack_char, tb);

  while (stack_pop(&stack_char, &tc))
      printf("%s\n", tc);
  ```

be sure to free the stack

```
    stack_free(&stack_char);
```

Using integers

```
    int a = 120, b = -32, c;

    struct gStack stack_int; stack_initalize(&stack_int, sizeof(int));

    stack_push(&stack_int, &a);
    stack_push(&stack_int, &b);

    /* or we can use */

    stack_push_arg_no_ref(&stack_int, 1776);

    /* we can now see the contents of the stack */

    while (stack_pop(&stack_int, &c))
        printf("%d\n", c);


    stack_free(&stack_int);
```